# In Safari select stops working after blur() is used to hide dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have logic that hides the select element dropdown by calling blur() on it. This works on all browsers but Safari. In Safari after you hide it with blur the dropdown will no longer show - ever. Here is a reproduction of the bug:

```js
var count = 0;

function foo(e) {
 console.log("FOCUSSSED\nCount: " + count);
 if (count < 1) {

  var c = this
  setTimeout(function() {

   c.blur();
   console.log("BLURRRRR");
  }, 200)
 }
 count++;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select onfocus="foo.call(this,event)">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Is there some kind of a solution to this? Or Apple should fix the browser mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of tinkering, I can also see but not fix this issue for you. Looks like Safari has implemented dropdowns differently, so the `blur` event doesn't actually hide the dropdown menu, but it does blur the field, which seems to cause it difficulties in trying to reopen the dropdown.

I can also confirm this behaviour when the select element is targetted by js and a event listener added to the focus event e.g.

```
var myDropdown = document.getElementById('selectizer');

myDropdown.addEventListener('focus', function( event ) {
    console.log("FOCUSSSED\nCount: " + count);

    if (count < 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            event.target.blur();
            console.log("BLURRRRR");
        }, 200)
        count++;
    }
}, true);
```

My best advice to you would be to recreate the select with HTML and CSS. You can do this with plain CSS like so:

```
.menu .option {
    display: none;
}
.menu:focus .option {
    display:block;
}
```

Just make sure you give your divs etc. a `tabindex` to show and hide the contents.

You can also do it with JS if you like, or use any number of off-the-shelf components you'll find with a quick Google.